# Any sideeffects for overwriting res.json to do prostprocessing?

Tags: express

Consider the following express middleware with the purpose of transforming a json response to one that supports [json api](http://jsonapi.org/)

```
var prefix = "/api/v1/";
app.use(prefix + "*", function userMiddleware(req, res, done) {

    res.jsonFinal = res.json;
    res.json = function(json){
        if(req.headers["accept"] === "application/vnd.json"){
            //postprocessing here
            res.jsonFinal(json);
        }else{
            res.jsonFinal(json);
        }
    }
    done();
});
```

As seen this overwrites `res.json` on a response basis.

This seems to work fine. However, I'm wondering: are there any sideeffects when doing this?